# SessionMap vs Map which is better for Session?

Tags: java, dictionary, session, struts2, session-management

Is there any advantages of using `SessionMap` over `Map` for a session in web application ?

1 advantage I found was you can invalidate a `SessionMap` but not `Map`.

Comment: SessionMap is managed by struts2, if you use Map then you have to manage at your end and its really painful to reinvent the wheel :)

Comment: If you are using it to keep a user's session, then definitely `SessionMap`.

Comment: There is no need to add the major tag in the title.

Comment: okay @Nomanaliabbasi is there any more advantages?

Comment: basically SessionMap is use to manage session in struts2, you can store/retrieve/remove and off course invalidate your session object, Map is core java feature to storing your data as key/value nothing much.

Answer (score 2):

The `SessionMap` is specifically designed for the purposes if you want to have access to the servlet session attributes. So, the user is able to keep a synchronized collection of objects in session and use it instead of `HttpSession` directly.

This object is automatically injected by the [`servletConfig` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/servlet-config-interceptor.html) which is a part of the `defaultStack` if you implement `SessionAware` interface in the action class.

As soon as you don't need to work with servlet session directly and don't have access to it you can at least invalidate a session that finalizes the collection of objects in it.

A new session map required to action context if you want to continue to use a session.

Comment: Hi! I've already read the documentation and some articles on the web, and I always read that sessionMaps store the session attributes. But what attributes are these?

Comment: The session map is used to store your attributes, that are stored in the http session as attributes, not in the reverse order.

Comment: Are these attributes instances of classes I create on my project?